# why access to some port isn't stable

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, telnet, port

we install the netdata tool ( its OS performance tool )

we notice that netdata installation failed on

```
curl -sSL --connect-timeout 10 --retry 3 http://localhost:19999/netdata.conf
```

and:

we notice that sometimes port 19999 is blocked 
and sometimes we have access

```
example when we have access

 telnet localhost 19999
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

and sometimes port blocked

```
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

**what could be the reason for this very strange behavior**

note - firewall is disable and stooped , also iptables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case

```
$ telnet localhost 19999
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

There is a process listening on the given port; you connect to it and eventually the remote end terminates the connection.

In the second case (here, I assuming you're specifying the same port since you didn't explicitly say so):

```
$ telnet localhost 19999
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

Here, `Connection refused` means that there is no process listening on the specified host/port.  Since you used a hostname, `localhost`, and since that hostname maps to both an IPv4 and IPv6 address, `telnet` tries to connect to both.  In the end, there is no process listening on the host (either via IPv4 or IPv6) on the given  port.

You can use the `ss` command to list what process is listening on what port:

```
# ss -nlpt
State    Recv-Q    Send-Q    Local Address:Port         Peer Address:Port
LISTEN   0         0           <address>:<port>                 0.0.0.0:*    users:(("<process-name>",pid=<process-id>,fd=<file-descriptor>))
```

The options:

- `-n` do not translate addresses to host names
- `-l` list only listening sockets.
- `-t` list only TCP sockets
- `-p` list associated process information.  You'll need root for this.

With that, you can verify that the process is or is not listening on the port that you expect.